# How to access to file that have been added as content in a separated assembly?

Tags: c#

I have a project that i put my reports files into it,now i want to refrence them in another ptoject,i tried this code:

```
StiReport.Load(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GoldAccountingSystem.Reports;component/StimulReports/TBank.mrt")
                    .LocalPath);
```

but i get this error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'E:\GoldAccountingSystem.Reports;component\StimulReports\TBank.mrt'.
```

`GoldAccountingSystem.Reports` is the assembly name of the reports,but i don't know why it's lookin in `E` for this assembly although the right address is `E:\Projects\GoldAccountingSystem\GoldAccountingSystem.Reports`.

And i think it's because the reports are added to the project as Content not as Resource.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you should try Relative Uri :

```
StiReport.Load(new Uri("/GoldAccountingSystem.Reports;component/StimulReports/TBank.mrt")
                    .LocalPath);
```

and absolute Uri should also work:

```
StiReport.Load(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GoldAccountingSystem.Reports;component/StimulReports/TBank.mrt", UriKind.Absolute)
                    .LocalPath);
```

Comment: I've already tried this but i get this error:`This operation is not supported for a relative URI`

Comment: Thank you buts it's the same thing,i wrote in the question.

Comment: I know,but the number of commas doesn't make any change.I updated the question,would you please take a look at that again.

Comment: check it I've added `UriKind.Absolute`

Comment: Thanks,Now i know the problem is that the files are added as content not as resource but i have no idea how to fix it.Thank you anyway.